# Try statement not catching the exception vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My exception isn't working for an excel file that is searched and returned with information. Below you will see that it cycles through the first column and returns information according to variables that are set globally. I have put an exception that if the try fails a message box will pop up and tell them it failed to find them, but its not catching it. Instead if the user isn't listed in the database it freezes the program.

```
    Private Sub ExceptionToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExceptionToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim objexcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    objexcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Global_Variables.SavedResults.UserM = Nothing And Global_Variables.SavedResults.UserL = Nothing Then
        objWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("filepath", [ReadOnly]:=True)

        objWorksheet = CType(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        Try
            For x As Integer = 1 To objWorksheet.Rows.Count Step 1


                If objWorksheet.Cells(x, 1).value = Global_Variables.SavedResults.UserD Then

                    Global_Variables.SavedResults.UserL = objWorksheet.Cells(x, 3).value
                    Global_Variables.SavedResults.UserM = objWorksheet.Cells(x, 2).value

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Exit Try


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("You are not in the Database.")
        End Try

        objWorkbook.Close()
        objexcel.Quit()

        ReleaseObject(objWorksheet)
        ReleaseObject(objWorkbook)
        ReleaseObject(objexcel)
        objWorkbook = Nothing
        objWorksheet = Nothing
        objexcel = Nothing
    End If

    Dim Email As New Email_Templates
    Email.Exception()
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it error on? Did you debug and follow the code - what is happening?

Comment: The should not be any exception in your code. Most likely, the loop takes very long time maybe because objWorksheet.Rows.Count is not the actual number of rows in your sheet, but a big constant. Probably you should set the count to the last row..

Comment: The error happens when someone that isn't listed in the database uses the program. The program freezes up because they aren't in it. The try statement should just throw them the you are not in the database. I get where you are going ASH. If the last row changes how can I account for that in my logic? Cause that might be the problem.